# How do I get Chocolatey to not add an EXE to the path?

Tags: chocolatey

Chocolatey adds any `.exe` it finds in my package install directory to the path (step #3 in [the wiki](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CreatePackages#okay-how-do-i-create-packages)). How do I disable this for a given `.exe` in my package? The `.exe` is a Windows Service and there is no need to add it to the path.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I have explained in the [official documentation](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/create-packages#how-do-i-exclude-executables-from-getting-shims):

> If you have executables in the package or brought into the package folder during PowerShell run and you want to exclude them you need to
> create an empty file named exactly like (case sensitive) the
> executable with `.ignore` suffixed on the end in the same directory
> where the executable is or will be.
>
> Example: In the case of `Bob.exe` you would create a file named `Bob.exe.ignore` and that file would not get a redirect batch link. The
> Chocolatey package has an example of that. To further expand,
> `bob.exe.ignore` would not work because it doesn't have the correct
> casing.